# "if" inside php's loop

Tags: php, loops, if-statement

i'm trying to make this code of `$vat1 - $vat10$` shorter by looping string

```
$vat1 = htmlspecialchars($_POST["vat1"]);
if ($vat1 != "zw" &&  $vat1 != "") {
    $vat1 .= "%";
}
$vat2 = htmlspecialchars($_POST["vat2"]);
if ($vat2 != "zw" &&  $vat2 != "") {
   $vat2 .= "%";
}
....
```

But it's not working correctly because of if statement inside it:

```
for ($x; $x <=10; $x++){
    $vat = 'vat' . $x;
    $$vat = htmlspecialchars($_POST["vat" . $x]);
    if ($$vat != "zw" &&  $$vat != "") {
        $$vat .= "%";
    }
}
```

I have read to use ternary operator inside loop, so I'm trying to make sth like this:

```
for ($x; $x <=10; $x++){
    $vat = 'vat' . $x;
    $$vat = htmlspecialchars($_POST["vat" . $x]) . 
                            ($$vat != "zw" &&  $$vat != "") ? $$vat .= "%" : "";
}
```

But still it doesn't make a good effect. Can you tell me how to make it right?

Comment: You should work on code formatting a bit (Such as indentation), it would be easier to tell what's going on in your code.

Comment: You need to set a value for the start of your loop - `for ($x; ` => `for ($x=1; `

Comment: How about you make it _proper_, instead of shorter? Stop using “numbered” variable names - use arrays!

Comment: @04FS Has a valid point. **WHY** do you need to move these values from a ___perfectly good array___ into scalar variables??

Comment: @NigelRen You are right :D so stupid mistake :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using variable variables, you could use the `${'vat.$x}` construct

```
$_POST = ['vat1' => 1, 'vat2' => 'zw', 'vat3' => '', 'vat4' => 4, 'vat5' => 5,
          'vat6' => 6, 'vat7' => 7, 'vat8' => 8, 'vat9' => 9, 'vat10' => 10
        ];

for ($x=1; $x <=10; $x++) {
//   ^^^^    Note I started the loop at a specific place 1 in this case
    ${'vat'.$x} = htmlspecialchars($_POST['vat'.$x]);
    if (${'vat'.$x} != "zw" &&  ${'vat'.$x} != "") {
        ${'vat'.$x} .= "%";
    }
}

echo 'vat1 = ' . $vat1.PHP_EOL;
echo 'vat2 = ' . $vat2.PHP_EOL;
echo 'vat3 = ' . $vat3.PHP_EOL;
echo 'vat4 = ' . $vat4.PHP_EOL;
echo 'vat5 = ' . $vat5.PHP_EOL;
echo 'vat6 = ' . $vat6.PHP_EOL;
echo 'vat7 = ' . $vat7.PHP_EOL;
echo 'vat8 = ' . $vat8.PHP_EOL;
echo 'vat9 = ' . $vat9.PHP_EOL;
echo 'vat10 = ' . $vat10.PHP_EOL;
```

RESULTS

```
vat1 = 1%
vat2 = zw
vat3 = 
vat4 = 4%
vat5 = 5%
vat6 = 6%
vat7 = 7%
vat8 = 8%
vat9 = 9%
vat10 = 10%
```

Or you could stick with the variable variable solution

```
for ($x=1; $x <=10; $x++) {
//   ^^^^    Again start the loop at a specific place 1 in this case

    $t = 'vat'.$x;
    $$t = htmlspecialchars($_POST['vat'.$x]);
    if ($$t != "zw" &&  $$t != "") {
        $$t .= "%";
    }
}
```

Will Also produce

```
vat1 = 1%
vat2 = zw
vat3 = 
vat4 = 4%
vat5 = 5%
vat6 = 6%
vat7 = 7%
vat8 = 8%
vat9 = 9%
vat10 = 10%
```

So basically all that was wrong with your code was you did not start the for loop correctly.